# Switch button, disable change state onClick

Tags: android, android-widget, android-switch

I want to use a [switch button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) but I want to disable the change status on click, let this change only to the drag option. I try to set `onclick` listener to do nothing but when I click on the button always change the state.

Some one know to disable the change status `onClick`?

Comment: use button.setClickable(false)

Comment: But if i setclickable(false) i cant drag the switch

Comment: you can use onTouch event for dragging...

Comment: if i setclickable in false the ontouch event only gets action_down events

Answer (score 3):

If you want to only change the state of the **switch** with swipe do the following:

```
 switchbutton = view.findViewById(R.id.switch2);
    switchbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switchbutton.setChecked(!switchbutton.isChecked());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a switch widget you will have to create your customSwitch class and override the onTouchEvent method to return true when you detect a click:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean response;
    switch (ev.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x = ev.getX();
            response = super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            response = Math.abs(x - ev.getX()) <= 10 || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;
        default:
            response = super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;
    }
    return response;
}
```

The number 10 is a tolerance value as some devices report a movement event of 3 or 6 pixels or so instead of a click, so with this you control: 10 pixels or less is click (and ignore it) or more distance is considered movement and let this movement pass trought normal switch behaivor.

Declare x as a class level variable, default value is 0.
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is allways called first so you will have x with the starting value on the X axis of the MotionEvent.

Comment: x is not initialised in the method. where to initialise x and what to put as its default value?

Answer (score 0):

```
//onClickListener
public void tglOnClick(View v) {
    ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton) v;

    //do something based on toggle status after clicking
    if (tgl.isChecked())
        //do something
    else
        //do something else

    //revert button state so that it can be controlled by some external logic
    tgl.setChecked(!tgl.isChecked());
```

}

This worked for me. In my case, the clicking the toggle button sent a request to a service, and if the service replied "OK", the message handler set the correct state of the toggle button.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later found a solution pretty clean and easy for this usecase :

Create your custom switch and override performClick(), that part allows to avoid CompoundButton to react at click :

```
class CustomSwitch @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : SwitchMaterial(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun performClick(): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

Second part is to forbid TextView inheritance to react at click and for that just add this to your XML :

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

Answer (score -1):

use [Toggle Button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) instead of `Button`

xml for toggle button

```
<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

in java class

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Im using switch button not a button. I want to disable the change state function on click and only let this function in the drag event

Comment: u can use that for switch button also

Comment: Yeah but the problem is the same, when you click the button that button change her state (on->off, off->on) and later enter in that function (onToggleClicked in that case). I want to prevent/eliminated the change state on click